# Display Html from database in a div

Tags: html, jsp

I want to display some HTML code from Database to UI , What should I have to do for it ?

My jsp code is like:
my data in db column(headerHtml) is `<h4><span class=/"_hide-for-small/">simple and secure</span></h4>`.

```
 <div>

   //change , data from db
      <%=userCard.customization.headerHtml%> // some thing like that

    <h5 class="_take-a-moment">Let's take a moment</h5>
    <h4 class="_3-steps">step3</h4>
</div>
```

I want output like :

```
 <div>

   // from Database
   <h4><span class="_hide-for-small">simple and secure</span></h4> //something like this

    <h5 class="_take-a-moment">Let's take a moment</h5>
    <h4 class="_3-steps">step3</h4>
</div
```

Comment: Now what is the problem you are getting ?

Comment: @Harshit org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:  I am getting this

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution of it . I did this , and it worked.

```
<div>
 <h:outputText value="#{UserCard.customization.headerHtml}" escape="false" />
 <h5 class="_take-a-moment">Let's take a moment</h5>
 <h4 class="_3-steps">step3</h4>
</div>
```